# How to call files in some order in a loop

Tags: shell

I'm working on a shell script that is supposed tu run python tests in some defined order. Here is the shell script:

```
files_array=()
for entry in tests/*.py
do
    files_array+=($entry)
    echo $files_array
done

cd tests/
./script -p create_01.yml
export FILE_PATH='../books/create_01.yml'
python3 -m unittest test test_create_01.py

./script -p update_02.yml
export FILE_PATH='../books/update_02.yml'
python3 -m unittest test test_update_02.py

./script -p delete_03.yml
export FILE_PATH='../books/delete_03.yml'
python3 -m unittest test test_delete_03.py
```

The "`tests`" folder has the 3 test files: `test_create_01.py`, `test_update_02.py` and `test_delete_03.py`.

I put the three files names in the variable array `files_array`. How to use this array to call all three files in one block instead of 3 ?
I also want to call them in some order: first call `test_create_01.py`, then `test_update_02.py` then call in last `test_delete_03.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to create an array. You can do it like this:

```
cd tests/

for entry in test_create_01.py test_update_02.py test_delete_03.py; do
    echo "now processing $entry"
    s="${entry#test_}"
    s="${s%.py}"
    ./script -p "$s.yml"
   export FILE_PATH="../books/$s.yml"
  python3 -m unittest test "entry"
done
```

Comment: Yes but the file path is a yaml file that doesn't has the prefix "test_"

Comment: I updated my question. Everytime I call the yml and the py files. Also your answer is not garanteeing that I would call delete after create not the opposite.

Comment: You know ./script calls the yaml file and not python file. Why : `./script -p "$entry"`

Comment: ok since you have only 3 files, you can try my updated script

Comment: awsome. I'll look after for some other solution in case I have a bunch of files.. for now that works! thanks